# "TypeError: toggleTask is not a function" in react.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web-applications

I started my first project in React.js and I'm following tutorial from youtube to learn some basics. I was fixing my problems right away but this time I can't do anything with it since yesterday.

I'm showing the code below, what's the issue? Why that error is showing up? Thank you.

This is App.js **code**:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import Tasklist from "./Tasklist";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = 'taskApp.tasks'

function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState ([]) 
  const taskNameRef = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY))
    if (storedTasks) setTasks(storedTasks)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify (tasks))
  }, [tasks])
  

  function toggleTask(id) {
    const newTasks = [...tasks]
    const task = newTasks.find(task => task.id === id)
    task.complete = !task.complete
    setTasks()(newTasks)
  }

  function handleAddTask(e){
    const name = taskNameRef.current.value
    if (name === '') return
    setTasks(prevTasks => {
      return [...prevTasks, {id: uuidv4, name: name, complete: false}]
    })
    taskNameRef.current.value = null
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Tasklist tasks={tasks} toggleTask={toggleTask} />
      <input ref={taskNameRef} type="text"/>
      <button onClick={handleAddTask}>Add task</button>
      <button>Clear completed</button>
      <div>0 tasks left.</div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

This is Task.js **code**, where the issue begin:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Task({ task, toggleTask }) {
    function handelTaskClick() {
    toggleTask(task.id)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <label>

                <input type='checkbox' checked={task.complete} onChange={handelTaskClick} ></input>
                {task.name}

            </label>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Tasklist.js **code**:

```
import React from 'react'
import Task from './Task'

export default function Tasklist({ tasks, toggleTasks }) {
    return (
        tasks.map(task => {
            return <Task key={task.id} toggleTasks={toggleTasks} task={task} />
        })
    )
}
```

Comment: can you please post the TaskList component?

Comment: just added to the post:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toggleTask` is passed to `TaskList`, but `TaskLists` doesn't destructure it, but instead destructures  `toggleTasks` prop, with an "s". `TaskList` then passes `toggleTasks` through to `Task` where it (*correctly*) attempts to destructure `toggleTask`.

Consistently name the passed `toggleTask` prop.

```
<Tasklist tasks={tasks} toggleTask={toggleTask} />
```

...

```
function Tasklist ({ tasks, toggleTask }) {
  return (
    tasks.map(task => {
      return <Task key={task.id} toggleTask={toggleTask} task={task} />
    })
  )
}
```

...

```
function Task ({ task, toggleTask }) {
  function handelTaskClick() {
    toggleTask(task.id);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type='checkbox' checked={task.complete} onChange={handelTaskClick} />
        {task.name}
      </label>
    </div>
  )
}
```